# HTML Table to PDF conversion using PHP

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation

I'd like to convert an html table into a pdf file using php. I don't want to
install or keep the library in the www folder.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/wiki/FAQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using the mPDF library. Here you have some [examples](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php) and [documentation](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php).It is really great. It works with
Look an example:

```
 require_once (dirname(__FILE__) . '/../pdf/mpdf.php');
 /*this is the constructor with different options :  mPDF([ string $mode [, mixed $format [, 
 *float $default_font_size [, string $default_font [, float $margin_left , float $margin_right ,
 *float $margin_top , float $margin_bottom , float $margin_header , float $margin_footer [,
 *string $orientation ]]]]]])*/
 $mpdf = new mPDF('win-1252', 'A4', '', '', 10, '', '', '', '', '');
 $mpdf -> useOnlyCoreFonts = true;
 $mpdf -> SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
 $mpdf -> WriteHTML("<p>here you put the html</p>");
 $mpdf -> Output();// this generates the pdf
 exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/index.php) library .

Here is full demonstration how you can convert HTML table into PDF

http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_006.phps

http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php